# Had to reset my android tablet and my google play app appears on the home but when I tap it it says app not installed!!

Tags: google-play-store

I can not  open google play store on tablet. app shows when tapped it says app not installed. I have tried going into settings and the app does not appear there to try to reinstaLL it. I have tried factory install also with no luck.

Comment: Sometimes app shortcuts stay on the homescreen after the app is uninstalled. Try reinstalling from the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly you’ll need a copy of the official Google Play Store apk file to install on your device. You can download this on your PC and move it over to your handset or download it directly onto your handset, in which case it will appear in your download folder. Either way is fine. You can download it from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1996995).Get latest version from it.
2. You’ll need to enable the installation of external apk files before you can install the Play Store file. This is done by checking the “unknown sources” box in your devices settings, which will allow you to install apps from unvetted sources, in other words from outside of the Play Store. This option can usually be found under settings > security, but may also appear under settings > applications on certain devices. You can always uncheck the box again after installing the Play Store.
3. You go to path where you store Google Play Store APK adnd then tap on it to install it and you are done.